# Using Subscripts and Superscripts in R console

Tags: r, rstudio

This is more for curiosity, but is it possible to write subscripts in R console and, if so, how would I do that?

- I am using a Mac and
- typically code in RStudio

Although assignment statements work with Greek letters, e.g. μ,σ, but I can't get superscripts or subscripts working. I'd like to write an assign statement such as `σ² <- 1` and have it be recognized. In particular, typing that last command I get the following error message

```
Error: unexpected input in "σ�"
```

Answer (score 1):

You *can*, but you shouldn't; names that don't stick to R's standards cause problems eventually.

The rules, from `?Quotes`:

> #### Names and Identifiers
>
> Identifiers consist of a sequence of letters, digits, the period (.)
>   and the underscore. They must not start with a digit nor underscore,
>   nor with a period followed by a digit. Reserved words are not valid
>   identifiers.
>
> The definition of a letter depends on the current locale, but only
>   ASCII digits are considered to be digits.
>
> Such identifiers are also known as syntactic names and may be used
>   directly in R code. Almost always, other names can be used provided
>   they are quoted. The preferred quote is the backtick (`), and deparse
>   will normally use it, but under many circumstances single or double
>   quotes can be used (as a character constant will often be converted to
>   a name). One place where backticks may be essential is to delimit
>   variable names in formulae: see formula.

If you still want to break the rules, there are a couple ways. You can use `assign`:

```
> assign('σ²', 47)
> `σ²`
[1] 47
> σ²
Error: unexpected input in "σ�"
```

Notice, however, that dependent on your locale, you may need to wrap `σ²` in backticks to call it successfully.

You can also wrap it in backticks to assign:

```
> `σ²` <- 47
> `σ²`
[1] 47
> σ²
Error: unexpected input in "σ�"
```

As you can see, you'll still likely need to wrap any calls in backticks (especially if you want your code to be faintly portable).

That said, this is all a REALLY, REALLY BAD IDEA.

1. Your variable names will be hard to type;
2. Your code will likely not be portable;
3. You stand a very good chance of causing errors in more complicated functions later (e.g. NSE functions would be very unpredictable);
4. It's a good way to do really stupid things:

like

```
> `+` <- `-`
> 1 + 1
[1] 0
```

The rules are there for a reason. Unless you've got a really good reason to break them, don't.

---

#### Addendum

If you just want to use symbolic expressions as strings, `encodeString` and `format` are both useful:

```
> encodeString('σ²')
[1] "σ²"
> format('σ²')
[1] "σ²"
```

See their help pages for more specifics, but it's generally possible to use any symbol (even emoji!) in a string, if you're a little careful what functions you pass it to.

Comment: Neither (3) nor (4) are convincing to me: (3), I think, is simply wrong: NSE treats these variables like any others. The only problem could occur if the NSE function calls `deparse` incorrectly (for backwards compatibility reasons, its argument `backtick` defaults to `FALSE` for most expressions, but it *must* be set to `TRUE`). (4) … I don’t really see what this has to do with Unicode variable names. You can redefine operators and other functions anyway.

Comment: @KonradRudolph For (4), sure, you need to be smart enough not to do such things. For (3), though, it may not be NSE (which can be implemented differently), but even `data.frame` normalizes the name `σ²` unpredictably to `σ.`, which if you didn't look (unlikely, granted) would cause downstream errors.

Comment: You can fix `data.frame`’s behaviour by specifying `check.names = FALSE`. People generally prefer that the default behaviour of `data.frame` is bad, which is why modern replacements, such as `dplyr::data_frame`, do it differently. You’re right though that caution is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I am using windows so maybe this doesn't work on a mac. The following code allows superscript for me.

```
    > assign("σ²", 3)
    > σ²
    [1] 3
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: This code is definitely not portable. R character encoding on Windows is a huge mess.